# Parse values to email template and rendering it in jhipster

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, jhipster

I could retrieve values to parameters in the following sendSportsMail method in MailSerivce.java.

```
@Async
public void sendSportsMail(String name, String email, String message) {
    log.debug("Sending feedback email to '{}'", email);
    Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag("en");
    String subject = messageSource.getMessage("email.sports.title", null, locale);
    Context context = new Context(locale);
    context.setVariable(BASE_URL, jHipsterProperties.getMail().getBaseUrl());
    String content = templateEngine.process("sportsEmail", context);
    sendNewEmail(email, subject, content, false, true);
}

@Async
public void sendNewEmail(String to, String subject, String content, boolean isMultipart, boolean isHtml) {
    log.debug("Send email[multipart '{}' and html '{}'] to '{}' with subject '{}' and content={}",
        isMultipart, isHtml, to, subject, content);

    // Prepare message using a Spring helper
    MimeMessage mimeMessage = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
    try {
        MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, isMultipart, CharEncoding.UTF_8);
        message.setTo(to);
        message.setFrom(jHipsterProperties.getMail().getFrom());
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(content, isHtml);
        javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);
        log.debug("Sent email to User '{}'", to);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.warn("Email could not be sent to user '{}'", to, e);
        } else {
            log.warn("Email could not be sent to user '{}': {}", to, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to parse name, email, message variable values to sportsEmail.html and rendering. So can anyone give an idea? sportsEmail.html is as follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title th:text="#{email.sports.title}">sports</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" th:href="@{|${baseUrl}/favicon.ico|}"/>
</head>
<body>
<p th:text="${name}">

</p>

</body>
</html>
```

There ${name} is a null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set your values in context, it's like a `Map`, see Thymeleaf's documentation.

```
context.setVariable("name", "someone");
```